# PlayFramework Scala dependency Injection Javax

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am new to Scala and the PlayFramework and am trying to figure out how I can do a a dependency Injection. I basically want a file that will be a trait and inject that into a controller. My problem is that my Controller class is not seeing my Trait this is my code

ProfileTrait

```
package traitss

import play.api.mvc._


trait ProfileTrait extends Controller {
    def Addone()
  }
```

Then I try to inject that into my controller

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

import traitss.ProfileTrait_
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import javax.inject._

class Profiles @Inject() (profileTrait: ProfileTrait)   extends Controller
{

}
```

However my controller is not seeing it, I am trying to follow the example here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection  .
I am using the play framework version 2.50

Comment: I took the underscore off, but the same issue persists.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't inject controller in a controller... If you have a common service, you should inject it in each controller independently.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject a trait directly. You need to specify the implementation of the trait that needs to be injected.

There are **two** ways to specify the implementation of a trait that is to be injected:

Using [@ImplementedBy](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Binding-annotations) annotation. Here's a simple example:

```
package traitss

import play.api.mvc._
import com.google.inject.ImplementedBy

@ImplementedBy(classOf[ProfileTraitImpl])
trait ProfileTrait extends Controller {
    def Addone()
}

class ProfileTraitImpl extends ProfileTrait {
    // your implementation goes here
}
```

Using [Programmatic Bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings)

```
package traitss

import play.api.mvc._
import com.google.inject.ImplementedBy

@ImplementedBy(classOf[ProfileTraitImpl])
trait ProfileTrait extends Controller {
    def Addone()
}
```

ProfileTraitImpl:

```
package traitss.impl

class ProfileTraitImpl extends ProfileTrait {
    // your implementation goes here
}
```

Create a module where you can bind the implementation with trait

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class Module extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {

    bind(classOf[ProfileTrait])
      .to(classOf[ProfileTraitImpl])
  }
}
```

With using the modules approach you get an additional benefit of enabling or disabling the binding. For example, in your `application.conf` file you can enable/disable a module using `play.modules.enabled += module` **OR** `play.modules.disabled += module`

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject a trait, you have to inject an object that implements that trait.

For dependency injection to work, you have to tell the framework (play uses Guice under the hood) how to resolve the dependency to be injected.
There are many ways to do it and it depends on your case, for more detail you can look at [Guice's documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted), the simplest way in play is to create `Module.scala` into your `app` directory , if it's not there already, and put something like this:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[ProfileTrait]).toInstance( ... )
  }
}
```

where in `...` you put the logic to create the object you want to inject.